# Adding CakePHP core features in an older version of CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.2, cakephp-2.3

I am using CakePHP 2.2 and I will probably need to use `SMTP` with `TTL` which is only available at CakePHP 2.3.0.

The additions for this new feature are documented here:
https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/734

And i was wondering where should I add this code in my CakePHP project as I guess the core folders should stay untouched.

Could I do it using the `app\lib` folder? In that case, how should I add the content? Do I need to follow any structure? How Cake would detect it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just follow the [CakePHP Migration guide](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-3-migration-guide.html) and update to 2.3.

Honestly, I didn't even read through the migration guide, I just swapped into 2.3 and everything has just worked. It doesn't appear that there are many changes to existing code - just improvements / additions, so you'll likely not have to do any code modification.

I like to keep my versions of Cake separate (see [advanced installation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/advanced-installation.html)), but if you're on the normal install, just replace the files within `/lib/Cake/` with the new versions files.

Comment: In your case (2.2 to 2.3), yes.  Going from 1.3 to 2.x is more complicated (as an example).